# Entity Framework Core 2.2.4 Duplicate insertion DbUpdateException deleted the original record. Is this even possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When a duplicate insert exception occurs, I found the original row got deleted when the illegal insertion tried to occur due to some bug in our code. Is this happening because of using the **DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull** action? What am I missing here? Nowhere in the code are we deleting records - no triggers, not even soft deletes.

Code below showing the exception thrown and EF Core generated DbContext entity.

**Code:**

```
public async Task<int> AddCampaign(DigitalCampaign campaign)
{
    try
    {
        await _dbContext.DigitalCampaign.AddAsync(campaign);
        return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"There was DbUpdateException error saving the Campaign {campaign.DcId} in OMS database. O1 SalesOrder: {campaign.OperativeSalesOrder.Single().SalesOrderId.ToString()}." +
            $"{Environment.NewLine} Error: {ex.InnerException}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(
            $"There was an error saving the Campaign {campaign.DcId} in OMS database. O1 SalesOrder: {campaign.OperativeSalesOrder.Single().SalesOrderId.ToString()}." +
            $"{Environment.NewLine} Error: {e.InnerException}");
    }
}
```

**Affected Entity:**

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.DigitalCampaign)
.WithMany(p => p.CampaignOperativeProduct)
.HasForeignKey(d => d.DigitalCampaignId)
.OnDelete(**DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull**)
.HasConstraintName("CampaignOperativeProduct DigitalCampaignId fk");
```

**Exception:**

```
There was DbUpdateException error saving the Campaign a088A000002CWrIQAW in OMS database. O1 SalesOrder: 30002231.
Error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'OMS.CampaignOperativeProduct' with unique index 'DigitalCampaignId and OperativeProductId together must be unique'. The duplicate key value is (2325, 11).
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreResults(Boolean& moreResults)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryNextResult(Boolean& more)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.<>c__DisplayClass187_0.b__1(Task t)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeRetryable[T](Func2 moreFunc, TaskCompletionSource1 source, IDisposable objectToDispose)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ClientConnectionId:d3869a6f-d7ba-4ed4-bae7-1e5a2c3f2e6a
Error Number:2601,State:1,Class:14
```

Comment: If you try to insert the same item twice in the *same* transaction, the error will cause the entire transaction to roll back. How was the original item inserted?

Comment: BTW you haven't posted the data modification code. This problem wasn't caused by configuration

Comment: The original record was inserted like an hour ago and not part of any transaction. The duplicate exception occurred on a resubmit of the insert request. This was during an UAT session and no tester had access to the backend. Just perplexed that an already inserted record got deleted when no delete api is exposed. Wanted to make sure it was no configuration issue or some quirk with EF Core